# How to search for 'String' and return value immediately following?

Tags: linux, text, grep

I have many text files that I need to search for a string, then return the value that follows. For example, my file might look like:

```
text
text
text
a =  12  b =  14 String =  25
text
```

I want to search for "String", then return 25. I tried using

```
grep -i "String" filename.out
```

but this gives me the entire line. I have found a lot of information for finding a specific string, but not what immediately follows. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
grep -iPo '\bstring\s*=\s*\K\S*'
```

Comment: what are the `\s` and `\S`?

Comment: @Smac89 empty char and not-empty char

Comment: Thank you! This does it. Quick follow up, what is the \K? I can't find it in the grep manual.

Comment: Kent, \b is useless. Can you explain why you put it, for some reasons?

Comment: @BMW, if you know what does `\b` mean, you would know it makes sense. for example, think about `OneString = 100` and `String = 25`, OP wants 25 instead of 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
grep -oi "String *= *[0-9]*" filename.out|grep -o "[0-9]*"
```

There are some sexiest way to achieve I think ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to to it with `awk`

```
awk -F "String =[ ]*" '/String/ {print $2}' filename.out
25
```

If there may be other variable behind `String`, use this:

```
awk -F "String =" '/String/ {split($2,a," ");print a[1]}' filename.out
25
```